# SvelteKit demo app starter: TailwindCSS not overwriting app.css contents

Tags: typescript, tailwind-css, sveltekit

Using the starter project from the docs [here](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/introduction#getting-started) I initialized a new project with:

```
npm create svelte@latest my-app
cd my-app
npm install
npm run dev
```

And used these template options:
[image]

Then following the instructions at [tailwind](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/guides/sveltekit) for installing with svelte, I should expect to see all the existing CSS reset, but the demo site remains unchanged.

When applying the same process with the skeleton project:
[image]

I see the CSS removed as expected. I am a new user of svelte and tailwind, but it seems like I'm missing something obvious here.

Answer (score 0):

A lot of the styling is contained in individual components, it will roughly look the same even if there is no `app.css` at all. Also, just to be certain, you might want to disable caching in your browser dev tools.